# API for electronic funds transfer

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal, payment

I need to periodically transfer money to my users' bank account. I don't want to force my users to have a Paypal account or some similar service, hence my preference for a plain simple transfer using the user's IBAN, just like the way Google Adsense pays its publishers.

Hopefully, I'll soon have a lot of users, so I'll be making a lot of transfers (thousands initially, hopefully move into millions), hence I'll need to automate this using a web service to perform the transfers.

I've been searching around and my question is: what services are available to do something like this, that operate worldwide (or at least in Europe and US)? Dwolla only operates in the US. It's not clear for me if Paypal or Amazon Payments offer this kind of service.

Comment: Have you spoken to your bank? Or checked with your accounts system provider?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can manually upload a file in a specific format to order several transfers to be done. My aim would be to automate this, hence mu question focusing on an API to do it. Banks, at least over here, won't provide you with an interface to upload such files. What do you mean by accounts system provider?

Comment: Where's "over here", as most banks over my here support BACS payments in an automated manner; with accounting systems making the most of the ability to integrate.

Comment: Hello, "here" is Portugal. I can manually upload a formatted file with transfer instructions on the bank's website, but I can't do it through software using an API. I'm trying to ascertain if there are companies providing such a service.

Comment: Uploading a file is still an API; why not build something to utilized that; even if only to create the correct formatted file

Comment: I understand what you mean. My purpose with this question is to understand if there is a service that, so I don't have to login to my bank's website (I know this can be automated...) and upload files manually (...as can this). Creating the correct formatted file is not a problem; automatic its upload is my main issue.